# Angular upload and back to main page

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have a simple Angular project that has some components. One of them is uploading a file to a local server by making a POST request to a NodeJS server sunning on some port. The app works as intended: when I select a file and click upload, the file gets sent to the local server and I can access it.

However, after I click `Upload` on my angular app, I get redirected to the address of my node server (in this case `localhost:8083/upload`) and an error page "Cannot POST /upload".
I assume this is because of my post request in the node server. See here the post from my server.js:

```
app.post("/upload", uploadFiles, (req, res) => {
    const dm = {
        file: req.file,
        message: `Successfully uploaded file to local file server   - @ ${Date()} `
    };
    console.log(dm);
});
```

What I actually want is that after I click on `Upload`, the page that I'm on to stay unchanged, maybe just update the DOM with a simple message `Upload OK` right below the upload button. How can I do this? Do I have to change something in both my node server and angular app or just the latter?

Thank you in advance!
Here are some snippets from my angular app:

**upload.component.html**

```
<h1>Upload</h1>
<div>
    <form action="http://localhost:8083/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <input type="file" name='SLURMlog'>
        </div>
        <div><button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Upload</button></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar> <- toolbar
<app-uploader></app-uploader>  <- the component that uploads the file
<app-fetch-data></app-fetch-data>   <- other component
<app-fetch-local-data></app-fetch-local-data>  <- other component
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not use Angular way of sending data. You use native html form with POST action, so your page behave like regular HTML. Submitting a form will redirect to the form action URL.

To do it correctly with Angular, you need to use Angular form directive to get the data from user input (text input, file input, ...) and then submit it manually to your server using Angular Http client service. The Http service make an http call behind the scene (AJAX call) without reloading your page.

See https://medium.com/@freecory/uploading-file-by-post-method-in-angular6-62d7e9705e94 for a basic exemple